# JQuery - how do i detect how many divs of a given class exist within a given div?

Tags: jquery, html, detect

I have a div like this:

```
<div id="x" name="x" class="x" style=""></div>
```

and contained within this div I have several divs like this:

```
<div id="y_1" name="y_1" class="y" style=""></div>
<div id="y_2" name="y_2" class="y" style=""></div>
<div id="y_3" name="y_3" class="y" style=""></div>
```

etc.

QUESTION 1:
How do I detect how many of these divs (class="y") are contained within the container div (class="x")? - (just an alert("") with the number, for example).

QUESTION 2:
How do I do something to each of these y-divs (class="y") such as a function that might place the letter "Y" into all of the y-divs using $('.y').html("Y"); , for example??

Any help appreciated guys....

Comment: Question 2, you answered in your question?! $('.y').html("Y");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to find the elements within the ancestor element.

```
$('#x div.y').length; // number of class y elements under element x
$('#x div.y').html('Y'); // run a jQuery method on the y elements
```

See the API:

- [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector)
- [`length` property](http://api.jquery.com/length)

Answer (score 4):

```
alert($('.x .y').length);

$('.x .y').html('Y');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//instead of $('#x .y') you can also use $('#x').find('.y')
alert($('#x .y').length())

$('#x .y').each(function(){
    //do what you want to $(this)
    $(this).html('Y');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
alert($('.x .y').length)
```

http://api.jquery.com/length/

Answer (score 1):

**1.** The `length()` method gets the total amount of returned elements:

`alert($('.x .y').length());`

**2.** You were correct in how to set the content on all of the returned elements:

`$('.x .y').html('Y');`