# jQuery - How to detect how many items and then assign a class to them

Tags: jquery

I have the following basic HTML:

```
<div class="row-wrapper">
  <div class="box">...</div>
  <div class="box">...</div>
</div>
```

...and I need to assign an additional class `.foo` to the inner DIVs that already have the `.box` class (keeping the `.box` class of course).

I need a way to detect when there are 2 DIVs inside `.row-wrapper`

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

I tried reading the jQuery API documentation for `.length` method but it's bit too complex for my jQuery knowledge.

I also read a [similar forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243554/jquery-how-do-i-detect-how-many-divs-of-a-given-class-exist-within-a-given-div), but they don't explain how to define the amount of items.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// If there are 2 or more children 
if($('.row-wrapper').children('.box').length >= 2){
    // add a class
    $('.row-wrapper .box').addClass("foo");
}
```

Something like the above should work.

EDIT: Since wirey suggests there may be more than one `.row-wrapper` - which is a valid point, we can do something like this:

```
// Loop through each .row-wrapper
$(".row-wrapper").each(function(){
    // If there are 2 or more children
    if($(this).children('.box').length >= 2){
        // Find .box elements within $(this), and add a class.
        $(this).find('.box').addClass('foo');
    }
});
```

JSFiddle provided by Jared: http://jsfiddle.net/zqyKn/

Comment: What happens when you have multiple .row-wrapper divs?  You will apply class `foo` to all divs with box under row-wrapper even if theres less than 2

Comment: Almost there! The thing is that other DIVs with `.box` within the page, also get the class added. I need to detect when there are only 2 DIVs inside `.row-wrapper`. Thanks.

Comment: @Ricardo - wirey pointed this problem out, and I added it in my answer above. Just loop through each of the `.row-wrapper`'s.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zqyKn/1/ This is updated to only support when `.row-wrapper` only has 2 and not greater than two.

Comment: Jared's code worked. The only difference in his code was `==` instead of `>=`. I like your code comments ahren, will keep them. However, the solution breaks as soon as you include any other element inside `.row-wrapper` but outside `.box`. Not a problem for what I need to do right now, but just FYI. Thanks a lot you guys!

Comment: @Ricardo - I have updated above to only check for the amount of `.box` children. Also, the `==` means equals to, whereas the `>=` means greater than or equal to.